# Corrupt password being pulled from wireshark data?

Tags: encryption, authentication, wireshark, tcp

Hello everyone,
                I currently have a pcap file that contains an unencrypted Telnet session, and when I trace the TCP stream the password is in a format like so: pas...ord (please note this is just the format not the actual password). My question is, what can  I do to be able to reconstruct the password fully? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried another capture to see if the same thing happens. You may just have a corrupt capture...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the hex dump say? In general, 8-bit and non-printables are printed as '.' by most viewers. Pretty much like this (just on a Linux prompt though):

```
$ echo H€llo | hd
00000000  48 e2 82 ac 6c 6c 6f 0a                           |H...llo.|
00000008
```

And here is an example of how to decode the hex:

```
$ perl -ne 'chomp; s/ //g; print pack("H".length, $_)' <<< "48 e2 82 ac 6c 6c 6f 0a"
H€llo
```

You might also need to figure out what encoding was used and convert it to whatever your teminal is using.